# How do I scan file or media for audio data?

Tags: audio, extract

I have an old PlayStation One game CD that has music on it that I want to save on my PC. How do I find and extract audio data from it?

Comment: You may want to include the title of the game, in case someone _knows_ the format in which the company ships their games and if there are tools too extract the files from that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the PS1 CDs have audio tracks like regular audio CDs. If that is the case, then regular "ripping" tools such as cdparanoia or EAC may be used.

Otherwise, you will have to scan the data file for known audio headers including [MP3](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html) and [PCM](http://www.ringthis.com/dev/wave_format.htm). It may also be wise to research what other audio formats were popular or common to use in PS1 games.

If the game studio have not yet perished, I would send them an e-mail asking for assistance in this particular case. If you manage to convince them that the audio is going to be used for personal purposes, it is reasonable to hope that they might provide you with information or even tools for extracting the audio.

Apart from that, there is this [thread](http://club.myce.com/f80/psx-img-files-how-can-i-extract-files-them-186657/) where someone has found a tool that may be working, but it's not likely to be applicable to your game because I doubt that there is a standard way to package PS1 games.